# Service Application Delphi

Tags: delphi, .exe, application-service

Como montar uma função dentro do service application que chama um `.exe`? Já tentei de tudo winExec, ShellExecute, até o creatProcess mas não está funcionando, alguém tem conhecimento na área para poder me ajudar.

Comment: Que erros te está a dar com o ShellExecute?

Comment: Nao abre o programa.

Comment: @WagnerVasconcelos qual o seu objectivo exactamente? abrir um bloco de notas por exemplo pelo projecto em delphi?

Comment: Isso, se eu conseguir abrir o bloco de notas consigo fazer as outras funcoes.

Answer (score 0):

Após muitas pesquisas encontrei a solução. Você deve ter os componentes JEDI instalados, então veja o exemplo neste site que funciona perfeitamente, é só seguir as instruções.
http://thundaxsoftware.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/how-to-run-application-under-active.html

Comment: Ajudar é sempre bom, mas sugiro que você dê uma lida nesse post: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links